# Laser 3D scanner is used in the movie to scan a key: technically possible?

Tags: scanning

[The Vault (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9742794/) movie has a scene at around 42' in which a laser scanner with a rotating table is used to scan a key in a short time, maybe some minutes:

[image: Scene]

No calibration is done whatsoever. The scan quality must be high enough for the replicated key to be useful.

Is it technically possible? Is it exagerated? Is it fiction?

Comment: Kinda off-topic here, but it seems plausible enough to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been instances where people have [replicated a key](https://hotforsecurity.bitdefender.com/blog/key-cloning-app-lets-you-or-a-stranger-copy-your-key-with-a-photo-18359.html) from a *photograph* of a key. A multi-minute scan of a key seems like overkill, but that appears to be a very *large* key so maybe so.

Is it possible? Yes.

Is it exaggerated? Probably much simpler than is portrayed.

Is it fiction? As portrayed, yes. Practically, no.